# How to fix disturbing screen while login to Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

Every time I log in to my ubuntu 14.04 LTS system, I encounter a screen as shown below(for 8-10 seconds).

[image]

Can anyone please give me an idea what might be causing this, and how to fix it?

Comment: looks like unsupported video mode... any video driver updates/proprietary drivers to try?

Comment: I don't think I am using any proprietary driver. Is that what you meant? Sorry, did not get you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should check for correct graphics driver updates.
i had similar problem in my windows 8 pc with no additional drivers.
And again with no updated graphics driver on my ubuntu machine. updated it and works great for me.